Hiltviewmodel in jetpack compose with AssistedInject multiple errors
I have a viewModel in my application that gets some runtime argument (Let's call it someId). As I searched I came across the AssistedInject functionality and updated my Hilt to version 1.2.0.
Now here is how I try to achieve this functionality:

On My first try:

In my MyViewModel.kt I have:
@HiltViewModel(assistedFactory = MyViewModelFactory::class)
class MyViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted val someId: Int?
) : ViewModel() {
...
}

@AssistedFactory
interface MyViewModelFactory {
    fun create(someId: Int?): MyViewModel
}

And in my composable I have :
 val viewModel : MyViewModel = hiltViewModel<MyViewModel, MyViewModelFactory>{factory ->
        factory.create(myIdVariable)
    }

and the result is, when I build the app, I get error :
[Hilt] ViewModel constructor should be annotated with @Inject instead of @AssistedInject.


In order to fix the error, I do these changes:

In my MyViewModel.kt I have:
@HiltViewModel(assistedFactory = MyViewModelFactory::class)
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @Assisted val someId: Int?
) : ViewModel() {
...
}

and when I build the application, I get this error:
on the generated MyViewModelFactory:
An assisted factory's abstract method must return a type with an @AssistedInject-annotated constructor.


On My third try, I do these changes:

In my MyViewModel.kt:
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @Assisted val someId: Int?,
) : ViewModel() {
...
}

and I get the same error.

So as it makes sense, I do these changes on my 4th try:

@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted val someId: Int?,
) : ViewModel() {
...
}


and again I get the same error as #1:
[Hilt] ViewModel constructor should be annotated with @Inject instead of @AssistedInject.

So, I've ran out of ideas how to fix the problem and what could cause the problem.
P.S. I've cleaned the project between each build, so that I make sure no old generated code remains, and all the DI is re-generated.

You need to update hilt to 2.49 or newer version:

Fixed #2287, #3523: Add support for using @AssistedInject with @HiltViewModel. (8327177).
For more details visit https://dagger.dev/hilt/view-model#assisted-injection.


Actually I implemented this feature in another feature and another branch. Probably it will work, but I will notify you for sore ASAP. Thanks.

I fixed it on another branch, and it worked. I updated it 2.52 and it just fixed.
